# Creating and sharing a git repository in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit

when I create a new maven project in Eclipse (version 2022-03) I run into strange problems that I don't understand. Probably I am just too stupid;-)

Let's say I have a project called HelloWorld and I want to put it under version control in the directory d:/git/HelloWorld

When I do that in Eclipse (Team - Share project) I get a dialog (Configure git repository) and when I try to create a repository d:/git/HelloWorld, Eclipse shows me in the target location "d:/git/HelloWorld/HelloWorld" - but that's not what I want.

I'd like to have a separate repository for each project, but directly under the top level directory "d:/git".

I have found out that everything's ok, if I create the git repository in the eclipse workspace but that's not what I want either.

How can I achieve this?  What am I missing here?

Strangely if I try to do the same thing in Intellij there's no problem at all

Surely I am doing something stupid - hopefully some of you can explain me what I am doing wrong here:

Thx a lot for your help,

Rudi

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the git documentation here https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#firstgit_with_eclipse
you'll find the missing part: you need to create the git repository before sharing. You can use the basic wizard to do 'create new git repository'.

[image: new git Repository wizard]

Then when you are ready to share the project, your repository will already be in the selection list for you to pick.

Comment: Hello Maxime,

thanks for your answer. I knew this possibility -  but this still does not solve my problem. Even when I create the repository before sharing, eckpse still wants to put the project in "d:/git/HelloWorld/HelloWorld" instead of "d:/git/HelloWorld"

Comment: Hello. I think this is related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15425640/1830268